# Плохое качество картинок в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: html, css, img

Ребятки выручайте. Есть сайт который я создаю. Сделал логотип сохранил в .png и загрузил на сайт. С компьютера всё выглядит суперски а вот с мобильной версии сайта размыто. При этом я пользовался тегом `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`. Сверил код с таких сайтов как VK и FACEBOOCK код html и css в точности похожи. Что делать? Дополню: вот скриншоты PC версии: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и мобильная версия: (Да линия чёрного цвета, я просто тестил @media)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение логотипа стало мутным так же как изображения капчи.

Comment: Зря вы отключаете масштабирование

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На мобильной версии 1 пиксель графики отображается 4мя, 9ю и т.д. физическими пикселями, в зависимости от плотности пикселей конкретного устройства. Соответственно, графика должна быть детальнее для показа ее на экранах с высоким DPI.

Есть 2 варианта:

1. Сделать картинки в векторном формате SVG (пора переходить уже на вектор).
2. Сделать картинки больше в 2 или 3 раза, и при верстке уменьшать их.

> (В коде css правила типа background-size не наблюдал)

Вот, например, VK, если вы мне не верите на слово:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему VK и Faceboock делают лого в .png точного размера и не уменьшают его? (В коде css правила типа background-size не наблюдал)

Comment: @ДанилПолянский Потому-что надо было смотреть в мобильной версии. Обновил ответ.